# How to get Terminal on OSX to start up clearly?

Tags: macos, terminal

I am new to Mac OSX. Once after i typed export command in terminal, each time i start up the terminal, two messages show up:
    `-bash: export: '=': not a valid identifier`

```
-bash: export: `:/Users/Li/File/Java/TStream': not a valid identifier
```

I know that clear and command+k can got a clean screen. But I just want to start up with a clean terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your terminal and type the

```
clear
```

command. This should clear your screen. Maybe what you're looking for is a way to have bash run that each time. If so, cd to your home directory:

```
cd ~
```

then edit the file called .bash_profile , or maybe .bashrc

On the last line write the word 'clear' without quotes, then save. This file runs when bash starts up, and the last thing it will do, therefore, is clear the screen.

For more info, checkout: [this](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashbehaviour)

EDIT:

Incidentally, I just realized you might want to clear the error. When you open up your .bashrc file, see if you can find a line that resembles the error you're getting, then comment it out.

Comment: Thx. It fixed after i modified the export command in .bash_profile.